# Bootstrap Video Jumbotron Height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My main objectives are to have a jumbotron where video plays, is 100% width of the screen and 70% of the height of the screen AND to eliminate the scrolling the odd scrolling behavior where when I scroll I do not want the video to follow. Currently when I scroll down the page the video follows. More details below on this.

Underneath the jumbotron in the body, I am using a nav data spy with a vertical navbar and when I scroll down the page the video scrolls with it. How do I stop that behavior?

Code:

```
<div className="jumbotron">
    <video className="video-background" preload="true" muted="true" autoplay="true" loop="true">
        <source src="example.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
    <div className="container-fluid" id="content">
        <h1 className="display-3">Heading Title</h1>
        <p className="lead">Sub Text</p>
        <a className="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#learnmore">Learn More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.jumbotron{
    position: relative;
    z-index:-2;
    height:62.5vh;
}
.video-background { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
    width:100%;
    height: 70%;
}
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated. I am using create-react-app if that at all matters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

For some reason you are using `className` instead of `class` attribute which I am not sure why, also you can only set one property, either `height` or `width` for the video, since the video needs to remain proportional, in the example I have set the width to `100%` and height to `auto`, then the video extends to the full width, also you need to remove all the padding for the jumbotron!

**Old:**

Just remove  `position:fixed`, what it does it fixed the position relative to the screen and not the website, hence you are getting the scrolling effect, I have used `position:relative` here to all the video to scroll, checkout the different CSS positions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

```css
.jumbotron {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
  height: 62.5vh;
  padding: 0px !important;
}

.video-background {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="jumbotron">
  <video class="video-background" preload="true" muted="true" autoplay="true" loop="true">
                <source src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="content">
    <h1 class="display-3">Heading Title</h1>
    <p class="lead">Sub Text</p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#learnmore">Learn More</a>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. That fixed my scrolling issue and thank you for pointing me to a good resource. However, the video still does not span 100% of the screen or the correct height. Any suggestions.

Comment: @dutterbutter Updated my answer please check!

Comment: Thank you that worked! and the reason for className is because of react.

Comment: Just to clarify, so there is no way to set a desired height for the video jumbotron? It must be set to height: auto;? For instance, if I do not want it to fill 100% window height but 65% and 100% width that is not possible?

Comment: @dutterbutter Its best if you do so, since you won't loose the proportions of the video, just set the width to any px or percentage and height to auto, there will be no loss of proportions then!